# Drive Failed now applications saying its already installed

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, hardware-failure

Recently one of my drives failed and all the application there are gone.

I've tried to uninstall using windows but it says that the application doesn't exist.

Now when I try to install any application, it says it is already installed and I cannot do anything, neither select any other location.

I know I can workaround it deleting every single register linked to this application, but it is time consuming.

Is there any efficient way to remove all the registers linked to the application automatically? Remember, windows didn't give me the opportunity to properly uninstall it, the application was simply removed from the list.

Comment: Did you give my answer a shot with the Microsoft tool yet? I just updated my answer to put the needed URL for the download link in there up top too. Additionally, the vendor of the product which installs on Window may have an uninstaller tool to cleanup orphaned items\objects which install onto Windows. Since they program the install process onto Windows, they would know best what to remove from Windows. I know this may be time consuming as well if you needed to get this for each app\program with the issue.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT i forgot to answer you. Yes, i tried to use the windows solution but had no success using it. I managed to make virtualbox to work deleting the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE/...` and it worked then i came to ask a better way. I tried to install photoshop that was giving me this problem, and no success either. I'm gonna search if they have a removal tool. But i might have more problems with other applications, thats why i asked. TY

Answer (score 2):

#### Is there any way to remove the registry entries for the non-existent applications?

You can use [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) by [Pirifom](https://www.piriform.com/) to do this:

> System Requirements
>
> Windows 10, 8.1, 8, 7, Vista and XP. Including both 32-bit and 64-bit
>   versions.

...

> We also offer a portable version for installing on USB thumb drives.
>   Visit the builds page to download.

It includes a [Registry Cleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/registry-cleaner):

> The Registry Cleaner will remove entries for non-existent applications, and it'll also fix invalid or corrupted entries.

The free version of [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) has this capability.

[image]

When you choose to fix any registry issues you are given the option to backup the registry changes.

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Pirifom](https://www.piriform.com/) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.

Comment: This solution did'nt work, even cleaning the registries. But still a good option to clean up unused registries.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the **Microsoft** tool for fixing this Windows problem located for download via the [Fix problems that block programs from being installed or removed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed) site via the [download](http://aka.ms/Program_Install_and_Uninstall) link.

Just download and install the **MicrosoftProgram_Install_and_Uninstall.meta.diagcab** utility once the download completes and then run to fix the related problems.

> ### Fix problems that block programs from being installed or removed
>
> - Follow these steps to automatically repair issues including corrupted registry keys that block you from installing or removing
>     programs:
> - Select the Download button on this page. In the File Download dialog box, click Run or Open, and then follow the steps in in the
>     Program Install and Uninstall Troubleshooter.
>
> > **Notes**
> >
> > - This troubleshooter might be in English only. However, the automatic fix also works for versions of Windows in other languages.
> > - If you’re not on the computer that has the problem, save the troubleshooter to a flash drive or a CD, and then run it on the
> >       computer that has the problem.
>
> [**Download**](http://aka.ms/Program_Install_and_Uninstall)
>
> > **What it fixes**
> >
> > - Corrupted registry keys on 64-bit operating systems
> > - Corrupted registry keys that control the update data
> > - Problems that prevent new programs from being installed
> > - Problems that prevent existing programs from being completely uninstalled or updated
> > - Problems that block you from uninstalling a program through Add or Remove Programs (or Programs and Features) in Control Panel
> >
> > **Runs on**
> >
> > - Windows 7
> > - Windows 8
> > - Windows 8.1
> > - Windows 10
>
> <sub>[source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed)</sub>